# How can I format this string that represents decimal number in my JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, casting, double

I have the following problem. I am working on a JSP page that use JQuery.

In this page I show some money amounts into a table, something like this:

```
<td width = "8.33%">
    <%=salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString() != null ? salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString() : "" %>
</td>
```

The obtained object (from the getTotImponibile() method) is a BigDecimal

In the td of my table it is shown a value as: **447.93**.

Now I have to format this amount in the following way:

1. Use the **,** character instead the **.** (for the decimal digits).
2. Show always 2 decimal digits after the **.** For example I can have only one decimal digit as 10,4 and I have to show 10,40 or I can have more than 2 decimal digits and in this case I have to show only the firs 2 decimal digits (for example 10,432 so I have to show 10,43)

So what can I do to achieve these 2 tasks? Actually I am showing a string that represent a decimal number. Have I to cast this value into a double or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a class (i.e. NumberFormat.java) and please put following methods in NumberFormat.java class:

```
public static String priceWithDecimal (Double price) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00");
    return formatter.format(price);
}

public static String priceWithoutDecimal (Double price) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");
    return formatter.format(price);
}
```

Now, in your jsp use code like this:

```
<td width = "8.33%">
    <%=salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString() != null ? NumberFormat.priceWithDecimal(Double.parseDouble(salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString())) : "" %>
</td>
```

This solution will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you had something like the following:

```
class Helpers
{
    public static String getMoneyFormat( BigDecimal money )
    {
        if ( money == null ) return "";
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
        return df.format(money);
    }
}
```

And then included it in your JSP page, you would then be able to do the following:

```
<%= Helpers.getMoneyFormat(salDettaglio.getTotImponibile()) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `salDettaglio.getTotImponibile()` instead of returning a number return a formated string using [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

And [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/format-number-with-custom-numberformat/) is a simple tutorial with example.

Note : Everything is in google

Comment: Pleasem can you show me a simple code snippet for my previos example?

Comment: I would use NumberFormat but, as JSTL as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I wouldn't format the number/value from the code since it is a task of the JSP (the view part of the project).

Why don't you use JSTL instead?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm

That way you will keep the value as it is, and on the other side, you can give it the format you precise depending on the view.